# Bootstrap CDN is not importing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following are in my head tags:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="boot.js"></script>
```

The last script is a reference to another file I am using to do all the jQuery code with. However the code below:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
        <nav class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </nav>
</body>
```

This just displays a white page. However if i use bootstrap cdn for JavaScript version 3.4.1 it works but not how intended (probably because its an older version). Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Remove the `navbar-dark` class. This class makes the link text white.

Comment: @Turnip Why did that make it do that?

Comment: Because it is designed to be used on websites with dark backgrounds. Read the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the dark background into navbar then add on more class `bg-dark` with `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">`

I think this will work.
Example is given blow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Popper JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <nav class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
          </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```